# Pluck query is working and select is not working in JOINS rails query

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 2 Models which has has_many relationship.

```
class CurrencyExchange < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :exchange_market_prices
end

class ExchangeMarketPrice < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :currency_exchange
end
```

I am trying the following sql output

```
mysql> select ce.code, emp.buy_price, emp.sell_price  from currency_exchanges ce inner join exchange_market_prices emp on ce.id=emp.currency_exchange_id;

+----------+--------------+--------------+
| code     | buy_price    | sell_price   |
+----------+--------------+--------------+
| cryptsy  | 392.96862470 | 390.74000000 |
| bter     | 392.00300000 | 392.00200164 |
| bitstamp | 393.78000000 | 393.77000000 |
| btce     | 388.82300000 | 388.56400000 |
| ccex     | 412.00000000 | 370.20000000 |
+----------+--------------+--------------+
5 rows in set (0.30 sec)
```

Equivalent rails query with select(Not working)

```
$ rails c -e local
    Loading local environment (Rails 4.1.7)
    2.1.3 :034 >  emps = CurrencyExchange.joins(:exchange_market_prices).select("currency_exchanges.code, exchange_market_prices.buy_price,  exchange_market_prices.sell_price")
     => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<CurrencyExchange id: nil, code: "cryptsy">, #<CurrencyExchange id: nil, code: "bter">, #<CurrencyExchange id: nil, code: "bitstamp">, #<CurrencyExchange id: nil, code: "btce">, #<CurrencyExchange id: nil, code: "ccex">]>
```

When I tried the pluck (working)

```
  2.1.3 :033 >    emps = CurrencyExchange.joins(:exchange_market_prices).pluck("currency_exchanges.code, exchange_market_prices.buy_price,  exchange_market_prices.sell_price")
     => [["cryptsy", #<BigDecimal:5e7b6c0,'0.3977857849 4E3',18(27)>, #<BigDecimal:5e7b648,'0.3954137660 3E3',18(27)>], ["bter", #<BigDecimal:5e7b580,'0.392003E3',18(27)>, #<BigDecimal:5e7b508,'0.3920020016 4E3',18(27)>], ["bitstamp", #<BigDecimal:5e7b440,'0.4E3',9(27)>, #<BigDecimal:5e7b3c8,'0.39901E3',18(27)>], ["btce", #<BigDecimal:5e7b300,'0.395714E3',18(27)>, #<BigDecimal:5e7b288,'0.394E3',9(27)>], ["ccex", #<BigDecimal:5e7b1c0,'0.412E3',9(27)>, #<BigDecimal:5e7b148,'0.3702E3',18(27)>]]
```

How should I change my rails query for **select** ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `#collect`, when you are using `#select` method. Because [`#select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-select) will give you the result *wrapped* inside the `ActiveRecord::Relation` object. You need to iterate though, and collect all your required attributes.

```
emps.collect do |rec| 
   { :sell_price => rec.sell_price, :buy_price => rec.buy_price, :code => rec.code }
end
```

Comment: <BigDecimal:5e2eca8,'0.3920020016 4E3',18(27)>], ["bitstamp", #<BigDecimal:5e2ebe0,'0.4E3',9(27)>, #<BigDecimal:5e2eb68,'0.39901E3',18(27)>], ["btce", #<BigDecimal:5e2ea78,'0.395714E3',18(27)>, #<BigDecimal:5e2ea00,'0.394E3',9(27)>], ["ccex", #<BigDecimal:5e2e938,'0.412E3',9(27)>, #<BigDecimal:5e2e8c0,'0.3702E3',18(27)>]] 
2.1.3 :040 >

Comment: @Jeff What do you want then ?

Comment: Arup - I need with column name not only values.

Comment: Arup - I want the same pluck query as in above with two more fields buy_price, sell_price. so that I can access each as a active record query.

Comment: @Jeff I have shown you how to _handle_ this. Anyway I have updated again. See, if it helps.